# Passing on current window location in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

In this code `$url` takes the value in `urlInput`

```
$URL = $('#urlInput').val();
```

If i need `$URL` to take the value of the current window location,the code doesn't work,i have tried

```
$URL = console.log(window.location.href).val();
$URL = (window.location.href).val();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: console.log(window.location.href) is enough to get the current window location, you don't need to add ".val()" method to get value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

val() method used to get values from input element only. so you try this code

```
  var $URL = $(location).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

```
$URL = $(location).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href` returns the current URL so if you want to assign that value to just `$URL`. Use this

```
$URL = (window.location.href)
```

Comment: but,what if .val(); needs to be there at the end?   
Orginal example http://jsfiddle.net/shrenuj/9Fhd6/18/
Add above code:  http://jsfiddle.net/shrenuj/9Fhd6/20/
the code doesn't work then

Comment: That url has 0 shares,so it there won't be any input
Revised working:
working: http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/9Fhd6/7/
After we change it http://jsfiddle.net/shrenuj/9Fhd6/21/ it doesnt work

Seems .val() is necessary.

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying but `window.location.href` doesn't have a propert `val()`, so you cann't call that.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var url = window.location.href || document.URL;
```

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` is a jQuery method (see [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/val/)), `window.location.href` is a DOM property (see [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)), you don't need to call `.val()` to get the `href`.